# How to remove url from print(in browser)

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net

I am printing html pages in c#. In the print function I have used

```
OnClientClick="window.print();return false;"
```

1. But the print comes along with the url in the header. How to remove this url?
2. I have a print button in the page and the button also comes in the print. How to remove this?

I am using CSS 2.0 so need a solution for CSS 2.0.

Thanks

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @page 
        {
            size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
            margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        }  I did this .But still get the print button

Comment: Did you try using CSS2 Media Types and setting `visible:none` when printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this and both the problems got solved.

```
    @page 
    {

        size: auto;   /* auto is the current printer page size */
        margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }

    @media print {
        #print {
            display :  none;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use print media query in css to hide button :

```
@media print {
 #button-id{
   display: none; /* This will hide your print button in print view */
  }
 @page {
    size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
    margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
  }
}
```